# Ignore invalid certificate with Axis client

Tags: java, soap, axis

I'm building a client for a SOAP webservice that is controlled by a vendor. Unfortunately their dev server has an insecure (self-signed) certificate that I'm unable to validate.  Apache Axis fails each time I attempt to make a request.  Is there a way to ignore SSL validation errors? I obviously don't want to do this for production but it would be good in my dev environment.

Comment: There is a related StackOverflow answer -- worked for me too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913185/ignore-certification-authentication-on-axis-client-for-wcf-service#10913791

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a number of solutions, what ultimately worked was installing a custom protocol handler and associating it with the particular `ServiceClient`:

```
private void configureServiceClient(ServiceClient client) {
       SSLContext ctx;
        try {
            KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            truststore.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/truststore.jks"),
                    "latitude".toCharArray());

            ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
                    .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(truststore);
            ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception loading Bold trust store", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        SSLProtocolSocketFactory sslFactory = new SSLProtocolSocketFactory(ctx);
        Protocol prot = new Protocol("https",
                (ProtocolSocketFactory) sslFactory, 443);
        client.getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CUSTOM_PROTOCOL_HANDLER,
                prot);
}
```

The advantage to this was it didn't require me to override all of the SSL connections for my application which could have potentially broken things down the road if new certificates were issued.  This one will definitely break if a new cert is issued, but it's only one connection rather than all of them.