# Axis2 2-way ssl handshake URL Filter

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, apache-axis

This is the setup I have

```
    Axis 2

    Java 6

    Websphere 7
```

After lot of issues made axis 2 work in Websphere 7 Now I need to implement two Way SSL handshake
Seems like I need to implement my own SSLProtocol Factory for apache httpclient.

But the catch here is .I need the ssl cert check only for a service deployed in it. There are totally two services.And I need the SSL check for only one service.

```
    Is there some url filter I can implement so That I can make sure the ssl 
    works for only the service I intend to not for the whole Project
```

Can anybody help me. been struggling with this issue for Weeks.

Comment: do you have an IHS(IBM Http Server) or apache sitting in front of your app. server?
When you mention you need ssl check for only one service do you mean you can have one service over plain http and the other with ssl muthual authentication?

Comment: @Marcos Maia YesI do have other services in the same war or other wsdl's in it. I need to enable ssl check only for a particular service/wsdl in the war. And we have deployed in webspshere.But we dont have any IHS in front of it. But if you could clarify who this can be done using IHS i can ask my SA to do it in our Dev server.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to write your own SSL socket factory that implements the filtering you want. As a starting point, Axis2 includes two SSL socket factory implementations that disable cert checking. [This one](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/ning/metrics.collector/1.0.1/metrics.collector-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies-sources.jar!/org/apache/axis/components/net/SunFakeTrustSocketFactory.java?format=ok) is for Sun java, while [this one](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/axis/axis/1.2/axis-1.2-sources.jar!/org/apache/axis/components/net/IBMFakeTrustSocketFactory.java?format=ok) is for IBM's JDK. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913185/ignore-certification-authentication-on-axis-client-for-wcf-service) has an example of setting Axis2 to use a custom SSL socket factory.

Comment: I wrote my own sslsocket factory but how do i configure it inside my AXIS2 webservice? Where should i have it class imported. In Axis2.xml or some other place inside code

Comment: Like I said, the [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913185/ignore-certification-authentication-on-axis-client-for-wcf-service) shows how to set Axis2 to use a custom secure socket factory. You could probably add the property to `axis2.xml` if you prefer.

Comment: My bad i must have missed it. Let me try that out. And get back to you

Comment: I could not figure out how to set the property in code or in axis2.xml.As I am trying set this up before the user of my webservice hits the WSDL. So where do I add this setting. We have requirement like the WSDL must not be even accessible by anyone other than the trusted source